# ¿Como cambiar el valor de qlcdnumber de manera autómatica con PyQt5?

Tags: pyqt5, openpyxl

Estoy haciendo un programa que lea valores de excel y los muestre con QLCDnumber, pero no logro este cambie conforme los valores son leídos en el documento de excel, por ejemplo quiero que primero muestre el valor de la celda A1 pero un tiempo después quiero que el mismo Widget me muestre el valor de A2 pero el valor se queda estático.

Los valores son creados a partir de la función random y son escritos en el documento de excel

¿Alguna forma de arreglar esto?

```
from PyQt5 import QtGui
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget, QVBoxLayout, QLCDNumber, QPushButton
import sys
import random
import time

import openpyxl

class MainWindow(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.title = "PyQt5 QLCD Number"
        self.setWindowTitle(self.title)
        self.setGeometry(200,500,400,300)
        self.InitUi()

    def InitUi(self):
        vbox = QVBoxLayout()
        self.lcd = QLCDNumber()
        self.lcd.display(60)
        vbox.addWidget(self.lcd)
        self.lcd.setStyleSheet('background-color:green')
        
        self.lcd.display(generate_temperature())

        self.setLayout(vbox)

    def update_lcd(self,value):
        self.lcd.display(value)
        time.sleep(5)

def generate_temperature():
    while(True):
        excel_document = openpyxl.load_workbook('test.xlsx')
        sheet = excel_document["Sheet1"]

        for i in sheet.rows:
            i[0].value = random.randint(0,10)
        excel_document.save('test.xlsx')
        return i[0].value

app = QApplication(sys.argv)
w = MainWindow()
w.show()
app.exec_()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Si quieres mostrar data cada T segundos(por ejemplo del excel) entonces debes convertir esa data en un iterador y usar un QTimer para que obtengas la información(no uses time.sleep ya que bloquea la GUI).

```py
import random
import sys

import openpyxl

from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets


def generate_temperatures():
    excel_document = openpyxl.load_workbook("test.xlsx")
    sheet = excel_document["Sheet1"]
    temperatures = []
    for i in sheet.rows:
        temperatures.append(i[0].value)
    return temperatures


class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.title = "PyQt5 QLCD Number"
        self.setWindowTitle(self.title)
        self.setGeometry(200, 500, 400, 300)
        self.init_ui()

        temperature = generate_temperatures()
        self.iter_temperatures = iter(temperature)

        self.timer = QtCore.QTimer(interval=500)
        self.timer.timeout.connect(self.read_row)
        self.timer.start()
        self.read_row()

    def init_ui(self):
        vbox = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self)
        self.lcd = QtWidgets.QLCDNumber()
        self.lcd.setStyleSheet("background-color:green")

        vbox.addWidget(self.lcd)

    def read_row(self):
        try:
            value = next(self.iter_temperatures)
        except StopIteration as e:
            self.timer.stop()
        else:
            self.lcd.display(value)


def main():

    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = MainWindow()
    w.show()
    app.exec_()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Si se quiere que se ejecute de forma ciclica entonces se debe usar un iterador ciclico:

```py
import itertools
```

```
self.iter_temperatures = itertools.cycle(temperature)
```

```
def read_row(self):
    value = next(self.iter_temperatures)
    self.lcd.display(value)
```

Comment: Gracias, el número si cambia, pero el ciclo acaba, ¿Hay forma de que el ciclo se repita? cuando llega a la última celda con un valor quiero que regresé a la primera y empiece a ller otra vez y mostrar valores de nuevo

Comment: @JoseChavez Tienes que ser especifico, nosotros no somos adivinos